# Lightweight alternative to Jetty

Tags: java, tomcat, glassfish, jersey, jetty

Usually **Jetty** is mentioned as *the* lightweight alternative when it comes to servlet containers like Tomcat and App Servers like Glassfish.

I want to run a RESTful service on CloudFoundry. Using jetty-runner

```
java -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar target/*.war
```

works kind of fine, except I kind of run into problems running Jetty 9.1.3 (current stable) /w **Java 8**. So I [contributed a patch](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430450) to fix this issue and some other minor code cleanup patches. Hereby I saw the code of Jetty which was not in a shape I hoped it to be...

Well I just don't want to entrust my enterprise app to Jetty and looking for alternatives. Also with **5.x MB, jetty-runner.jar** is still huge. I managed to **strip it down to 1.6 MB** and I was still able to run my app. So an even more lightweight approach is feasible.

Is there a lightweight version of GlassFish or Tomcat. **I just need the servlet-api.jar (v3.1) being run in a web server context. No JSP, no websocket-server, no other Voodoo.**

Comment: Is Jetty not lightweight enough? Its quality is not trustworthy? The history of the patch you contributed shows that Your problem was caused by using conflicting ASM versions. It wasn't Jetty fault. Sorry, but whole your question looks like... rant.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Undertow is a flexible performant web server written in java,
>   providing both blocking and non-blocking API’s based on NIO.
>
> Undertow has a composition based architecture that allows you to build
>   a web server by combining small single purpose handlers. The gives you
>   the flexibility to choose between a full Java EE servlet 3.1
>   container, or a low level non-blocking handler, to anything in
>   between.
>
> Undertow is extremely lightweight, with the Undertow core jar coming
>   in at under 1Mb. It is lightweight at runtime too, with a simple
>   embedded server using less than 4Mb of heap space.

Link to [official site](http://undertow.io/).

Comment: I'm looking for a code snippet how to launch a web app that is defined in my web.xml; http://undertow.io/documentation/servlet/deployment.html is empty at the moment.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you need: https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/tree/master/examples

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found any example that starts an http server based on a web.xml configuration.

Comment: I think you need to pack the web.xml file in the *.war archive. Perhaps it will be helpful: https://github.com/undertow-io/jastow/blob/master/src/test/java/io/undertow/test/jsp/basic/SimpleJspTestCase.java and https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-198

Comment: It is relatively straightforward to write some code to parse a simple web.xml and configure Undertow with the defined servlets, mappings, init params and so on. I can understand why Undertow team leaves full war support including web.xml to WildFly...

Comment: @jugglingcats - no, it's not straightforward at all.

Comment: Comparing undertow-servlet 2.1.0 and jetty-servlet 9.4.33 (and include all dependencies in a fat JAR) undertow has 4MB and Jetty only 2MB...

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged this as Jersey, I'll mention that the Jersey docs show examples of how to deploy using the HTTP server that is built-in to the Java runtime:

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.http

Comment: Unfortunately the Jersey container does not support any servlet deployment descriptors, i.e. web.xml and the Servlets that have been defined there.

Answer (score 0):

Going through [Pippo](http://www.pippo.ro/) system requirements, I found [TJWS - Tiny Java Web Server and Servlet Container](http://tjws.sourceforge.net/), BSD license.